# Physical relevance of either fundamental identity generalizing Jacobi

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, lie-algebras, string-theory

There are two fundamental identities for n-ary generalizations of the Jacobi identity.
One fundamental identity is right for Nambu mechanics and such, the other for L_\infty algebras as in CSFT.
Which is physically relevant for double field theory? For fluxes?

Comment: I am inclined to say that questions about "physical relevance" may be off-topic for MathOverflow. But maybe I an not correctly understanding the term. Can you clarify a bit?

Comment: I would love to read answers to this question, and might even have things to say, but as written the question is a bit opaque.  Maybe you could elaborate a bit?